# jquery mobile: how to prevent header/footer show up when click certain element

Tags: jquery-mobile

html :

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true" >
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" id=""#article-page"> 
...
```

I'd like to prevent header/footer show up when swipe left/right or click a certain element in contents;
Otherwise, let header/footer show.

i tried preventDefault, not working.

```
$("#article-page").bind("swipeleft", function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    navidown();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true" 
     data-tap-toggle="false">
```

data-tap-toggle added.

```
$( "div[data-role=header]" ).toolbar( "hide" );
```

[API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/toolbar/#method-hide)